# Updating a value using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created a shortlist system, its like what is used on realestate websites so you can make a list of favorites (using a session arrray) which you can come back to. The system uses jquery to update the session array with a new shortlist item.

What I am not sure how to do is update the 'shortlist/ array count' using jquery. I know how to change the HTML of an id, but how could I retrieve the session count and + 1 when something has been added a new item to the array. Here is how I display my 'shortlist count':

Shortlist: " ([view](/shortlist))

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the shortlist/array count".  Do you just mean counting the number of items?  If so then isn't that trivial in JavaScript?

Comment: The jquery passes data to php which is added to an array. The total items in the array are shown on the page (like items in checkout in a shopping cart). I am looking to update this value using jquery, was thinking of retrieving the value either of the div/ array count and adding 1

Comment: If that array is on server, then you need to make ajax call which will tell server what to add to cart, and server should return new number to show (as he could add something from another tab)

Comment: I have added the item to the cart, I need to know how to update the value without refreshing the page in jquery. Everything works fine is I refresh the page

Comment: please post html source of the part which shows the count

Comment: I thought I had added that into the post:

Comment: <div id="shortlist"><? echo  count($_SESSION['shortlistArray']); ?>" (<a href="/shortlist">view</a>)
  </div>

Comment: That is php code, not html, but I will try to deduce how html looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until you post code of element containing the html of the part of page you want to update, no one will be able to help you much, but lets say that you have something like this:

```
<div id="shortlist">
    You have <span id="itemCount">2</span> items in your cart.
</div>
```

You can update value from jQuery like this:

```
var oldValue = $("div#shortlist").find("span#itemCount").text();
var newValue = parseInt(oldValue) + 1;
$("div#shortlist").find("span#itemCount").text(newValue);
```

Updating your html, which looks like:

```
<div id="shortlist">3 (<a href="/shortlist">view</a>) </div>
```

would be much simpler if you would change php to something like:

```
<div id="shortlist"><span id="itemCount"><? echo count($_SESSION['shortlistArray']); ?></span>" (<a href="/shortlist">view</a>) </div>
```

It is good to have value to update in html element you can identify through jQuery. If this is not option, then you need to update value using string.replace (probably searching for regex if you don't now old value?).